# codeigniter form_validation returning false

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

Can anyone help me why is my code returning `if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)` . I am a begginer in codeigniter and i want to use form_validation to match the rules of changing password. I only want is to return the statement form_validation to true so that i can proceed on updating in database.

I already loaded form_validation,url etc.
My callback_oldpassword code works fine so,i dont need to cover it in my question. So nevermind the callback it already returns true.

what i want is to focus on my password match ?. i think it is there the wrong doing. Can anyone help me find out what happens. ? to return the form_validation into true based on the rules that i've declared.

Here is my form:

```
<form id="pass_form" class="form-horizontal">

    <?php $userid = ($this->session->userdata['logged_in']['user_id']); ?>
                                                        <input type="hidden" name="userid" id="userid" value="<?php echo $userid ?>" />

    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="curPword">Current Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="curPword" id="curPword" placeholder="Enter current password" required />
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="newPword">New Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="newPword" id="newPword" placeholder="Enter new password" required />
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="confPword">Confirm Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="confPword" id="confPword" placeholder="Confirm new password" required />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 ajax_pass_result"></div>
    </div>
    <button onclick="changepass(event)" class="btn btn-success btn-sm "><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Update Password</button>
</form>
```

my ajax:

```
function changepass(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:  "<?php echo site_url('manager/profile/update_password') ?>",    
    data: $("#pass_form").serialize(),
    success: function(res) {
        $(".ajax_pass_result").html(res);

     }
    });

}
```

and my controller where the form_validation always returns false:

```
public function update_password() {


        $config = array(
            array(
                'field'   => 'curPword',
                'label'   => 'curPword',
                'rules'   => 'trim|required|callback_oldpassword_check' // Note: Notice added callback verifier.
            ),
            array(
                'field'   => 'confPword',
                'label'   => 'confPword',
                'rules'   => 'trim|required|matches[password]'
            ),
            array(
                'field'   => 'newPword',
                'label'   => 'newPword',
                'rules'   => 'trim|required'
            ));
        $this->form_validation->set_rules($config);

         if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
               echo 'Error in password fields !';  
         }
         else {
              unset($_POST);
              $message = "No Error ";
              echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
          }
  }
```

Comment: U need to use <?php echo validation_errors(); ?> in view this will tell u what actual  u r getting.

Comment: You've fallen for the trap of using compressed words ( for want of a better term) and then falling back to using full words... IN your rules where you have the entry matches[password], where is password? Is it not supposed to be curPword or currentPassword, which reads a whole lot nicer. The extra Keypresses required to spell out words in full dont (does not) cost you anything...

Comment: @TimBrownlaw thank you for your answer how can i change it sir ?. . i dont understand what hppen .. can you answer ?

Comment: @devpro hello sir, thanks for your answer. i have no errors in my console. do i need to do echo valid_errors(); ? where would i put it  ? inside the false ?

Comment: Add this in view file this will tell u the actual error

Comment: Well just to get you going change matches[password] to matches[curPword] as that is the item you are wanting to match against.

Comment: @devpro sir it gives me error The confPword field does not match the password field.

Comment: Field name issue, answer posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to change rule for confirm password validation as:

```
array( 'field' => 'confPword', 'label' => 'confPword', 'rules' => 'trim|required|matches[curPword]' ),
```

What actually you are using, you are using `matches[password]` but your password field name is `matches[curPword]`

Comment: thank you very much sir.. i've learned something in you. echo validation_errors();

Comment: @jc-john glad to help u